# SQL Server XQuery - only works with namespace declarations removed

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I am completely green with XQuery. My code comes straight from this post: **[SQL server xquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951552/sql-server-xquery)**

However, my XML data includes some namespace information (which I assume is quite common), and the query only works if I remove these. Example:

```
declare @x xml=
'<WeatherReturn
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
    <City>Dallas</City>
    <State>TX</State>
    <Temperature>55</Temperature>
</WeatherReturn>'

select  t.s.value('City[1]','nvarchar(20)') [City],
        t.s.value('State[1]','nvarchar(20)') [State],
        t.s.value('Temperature[1]','nvarchar(20)') [Temperature]
from    @x.nodes('WeatherReturn') t(s)
```

As is, the query returns three blank columns. But remove the 3 "xmlns:" lines, and I get proper results.

Can someone please explain this behavior and what I need to do to overcome it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`WITH XMLNAMESPACES`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177607.aspx)

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/')
select  t.s.value('City[1]','nvarchar(20)') [City],
        t.s.value('State[1]','nvarchar(20)') [State],
        t.s.value('Temperature[1]','nvarchar(20)') [Temperature]
from    @x.nodes('WeatherReturn') t(s);
```

(make sure the preceding statement is terminated with a semicolon)

Comment: I had a feeling something like this was the case. I'll read up on your link. Thanks!